# How do I check if an input is in fact in a column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Example of the dataFrame:

```
df = {'column': 'hello'}
```

The input should be an entry in the dataFrame

```
if 'hello' in df['column']:
   print("hello")
else:
  print("Couldn't find entry)
```

What I would want as the output would be:

```
Hello
```

However, the output comes out as:

```
Couldn't find entry
```

I've checked and the value entered in the input is definitely inside that column of the dataFrame
I don't know if im doing anything incorrectly or why it is not working

Comment: I think if you replace `if 'hello' in df['column']:` with `if 'hello' in df['column'].tolist():`, it might work.

Comment: @Sajan Thanks a lot! it worked with  .tolist(). Do you happen to know why it doesn't just work as I wrote it?

Comment: `tolist()` function would convert the values of a dataframe column into a `list` and then, one could loop through it. I tried your code but it gave an error. Not sure but maybe, dataframe values cannot be accessed like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and comment whether it gives the correct output

```
df = {'column': 'hello'}
if 'hello' == df['column']:
   print("hello")
else:
  print("Couldn't find entry")
```

Comment: thanks, I meant to write my question as your first example. I've edited it now, however my problem still remains the same

Comment: Do you happen to know why it works when comparing ("==") and not when using in?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got the correct output:

```
df = {'column': 'hello'}

if 'hello' in df['column']:
   print("hello")
else:
  print("Couldn't find entry")
```

**Output:**

```
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Use df.values:

```
for i in df.values:
 if 'hello' in i:
    print("hello")
 else:
    print("Couldn't find entry")
```